# Working iron tile doesn't produce any iron output

Tags: civilization-5

Fairly new to this game, but it's my understanding that to gain more strategic resource output, that resource must be worked. I'm working three iron mines, 1 in my capital adjacent to the city tile that yields 2, and 2 in another city that yields 6 and 2 (not adjacent to the city tile). By working them I mean I've checked them in the city view so they're green.

Still, my overall iron output is only 2, and is used up by 2 longswordmen units, so I can't produce any catapults.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To gain strategic resources, they **do not need to be worked** by your city's civilians.

Rather, you need only to **improve a resource tile** within your borders with some tile improvement. For iron, these are mines. Make sure that your workers have built mines over all of your iron deposits. Additionally, resources are lost if the improvement tile is occupied by an unfriendly unit or if the tile improvement on it is pillaged.

Great people's improvements provide resources (but not yield bonuses) once you have researched the required technology.

It sounds like perhaps you have built a mine on a single resource providing 2 iron, and the other two resources are being worked, but are unimproved.

Comment: Well no, there are mines over all three. And only two iron-requiring units. I should gain a surplus then, right? They're supposed to yield a total of 10.

Comment: Yes, if that's the case it sounds like it may be a bug.. You're not trading any away, are you?

Comment: As stated, the mines weren't finished. They looked a awfull lot like complete mines though :)

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to tell sometimes! If this answer helped, please mark it as accepted. (And welcome to the site, btw!)

Comment: @AkselMathias Please mark the answer as accepted instead of proposing an edit. :)

Comment: @Schism Yes ofcourse. Sorry.